# Default lambda as templated parameter of a function

Tags: c++, templates, lambda, c++17, default-parameters

Consider the following code

```
template<bool b, typename T> void foo(const T& t = []() {}) {
  // implementation here
}

void bar() {
  foo<true>([&](){ /* implementation here */ }); // this compiles
  foo<true>(); // this doesn't compile
}
```

In the case that doesn't compile I get the following errors:

```
error C2672: 'foo': no matching overloaded function found
error C2783: 'void foo(const T&)': could not deduce template argument for 'T'
```

I think it's clear what I want to achieve: let `foo` be called with and without a client-provided lambda. The compiler is MSVC++2017 version 15.4.4 toolset v141.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The compiler uses the arguments *passed* to deduce the template type. If there's no arguments, then how would the compiler be able to deduce the template type?

You can use *overloading* instead of default arguments here.

The overloaded non-argument function can simply call the function with the "default" argument:

```
template<bool b, typename T> void foo(const T& t) {
  // implementation here
}

template<bool b> void foo() {
  foo<b>([]() {});
}
```

Comment: The first paragraph doesn't make much sense. There may be no explicit arguments, but the compiler could use the default ones as if they were specified on the call site; the standard goes to great lengths to exclude this case which suggests that it's not that unreasonable to expect it to work. I suspect that the real culprit here is that adding this extra flexibility would complicate the overload resolution process even more, and it's already a clusterfuck enough.

Answer (score 8):

Default function arguments are not part of the template argument deduction process. To quote [[temp.deduct.partial]/3](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/temp.deduct#partial-3):

> The types used to determine the ordering depend on the context in
>   which the partial ordering is done:
>
> - In the context of a function call, the types used are those function parameter types for which the function call has arguments.
>     <sup>141</sup>
>
> <sub>141) Default arguments are not considered to be arguments in this
>   context; they only become arguments after a function has been
>   selected.</sub>

That bullet and note indicate that since you didn't provide an argument for `t` in the call to `foo`, the type `T` cannot be deduced. The default lambda argument can only be taken into account if the function is selected to be called, not before.

The solution, as all the others have noted, is to provide an overload without parameters, that will call the templated one with the default lambda you have in mind.

Answer (score 4):

Another (very efficient) way - default T to be a null functor.

```
// no_op is a function object which does nothing, regardless of how many
// arguments you give it. It will be elided completely unless you compile with
// -O0
struct no_op 
{ 
    template<class...Args>
    constexpr void operator()(Args&&...) const {} 
};

// foo defaults to using a default-constructed no_op as its function object
template<bool b, typename T = no_op> void foo(T&& t = T()) 
{    
  // implementation here
    t();
}

void bar() {
  foo<true>([&](){ std::cout << "something\n"; }); // this compiles
  foo<true>(); // this now compiles
}
```

Comment: IMHO, this is better than the accepted answer.     To other readers, please don't think that this answer is too long.   The last lines (`bar()`) are just testing.

Comment: This is actually shorter than the accepted answer in many cases, as you need to define `no_op` only once in a program. Once the boilerplate is out of the way in a header file, the actual usage is much simpler and has no code repetition.

Answer (score 1):

Consider overloading it directly:

```
template <bool b>
void foo(void) {
  foo([](){});
}
```

See [CppReference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_argument_deduction):

> #### Non-deduced contexts
>
> 4) A template parameter used in the parameter type of a function parameter that has a default argument that is being used in the call for which argument deduction is being done:

> Type template parameter cannot be deduced from the type of a function default argument:
>   template void f(T = 5, T = 7);
>
> ```
> void g()
> {
>     f(1);     // OK: calls f<int>(1, 7)
>     f();      // error: cannot deduce T
>     f<int>(); // OK: calls f<int>(5, 7)
> }
> ```

Comment: I'm not sure this is required to work - I don't think that the standard mandates that two "instances" of the same lambda have the same type.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to say something that makes no sense. You are asking the compiler to guess `T` from your arguments, but then you do not provide any argument.

The following code does compile, and does what you want:

```
template<bool b, typename T> void foo(const T& t) {
  // implementation here
}

template<bool b> void foo() {
  foo<b>([]() {}); // Call actual implementation with empty lambda
}

void bar() {
  foo<true>([&](){ /* implementation here */ }); // this compiles
  foo<true>(); // this now compiles as well
}
```